# Numpad not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, numpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numeric keypad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4473/numeric-keypad-not-working)

I can't really understand why this is not working and maybe this is a bug, but it used to work as I rememeber and is working correctly under Windows.

I have 3 keyboard layouts in preferences, 1 the default for the keyboard (Norvegian) plus English and Romanian. Is not working not even in the default one. I did not change anything lately except Ubuntu updates.

If you need some config from me just ask.
Thanks.